# Trying to replace a button's link, work on every browser except Safari?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, safari

I am trying to replace the url and do some action. If my site www.mysite.com/hello had hello, then I will replace a button link. The url detection function works, because I place alert(), it popup. so the attr replace give me the problem. It works on every browser except Safari, how can I fix this?

```js
if(window.location.href.indexOf("hello") > -1) {
    $('#ladies_fashion').attr("href", "http://myshite.com/replace/");
}/*slim-tee*/
```

```html
<a id="ladies_fashion" href="http://myshite.com/ladies/" title="Antioxidant">Fashion Inspiration</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

I figure it out by myself. I have to add the http://